# Como tratar sessão expirada dentro do modal bootstrap 4.x?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, session

Tenho um sistema onde o usuário escolhe uma data e hora pra agendamento, eu aumentei o tempo de sessão pois o usuário precisa preencher um formulário com informações diversas, está funcionando beleza.

Acontece que depois de expirada a sessão o navegador mantém a página em exibição, quando o usuário clica aparece a janela modal bootstrap com a pagina index para o usuário fazer login novamente, esse comportamente de "re-login" já é esperado.

O problema é que a tela de login aparece dentro do modal bootstrap, eu gostaria que aparece-se na janela toda senão confunde o usuário, pois quando ele loga novamente ele vai pra página inicial.

Existe uma forma própria de tratar isso ou vou ter que verificar qual janela esta sendo aberto no modal?

Comment: Amigo poderia explicar melhor, não consegui entender muito bem o seu problema.

Comment: Quando o usuário clica num botão agendar aparece pra ele um popup (modal do bootstrap) com a pergunta Sim ou Não, se a sessão expirou dentro dessa tela aparece a pagina inicial pra ele logar novamente, isso é um tratamento interno do sistema... o unico problema é que aparece dentro da janela modal... eu gostaria que aparece a página index do sistema fora da janela modal, ou seja é como se ele tivesse entrando no sistema pela primeiro vez

Comment: Você tem duas maneiras de resolver isso, a primeira e mais rápida é quando a sessão expirar redireciona ele pro login, assim não confunde o usuário. A segunda opção é você armazenar a tela que ele está acessando, assim quando a sessão expirar vc exibi o modal de login e depois já redireciona ele para a página de onde ele parou.